# How to use tensorflow-gpu GPUOptions

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow-gpu so I can run my models faster but I don't really understand how I can activate it. At the moment my code looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

gpu_options = tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(set_per_process_memory_fraction(0.333))
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

But this code obviously doesn't work and I am how to use it. I already looked on the official tensorflow website documentation but it's really confusing.
Can someone please tell me how to use it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are running tensorflow version 2.0. In which case you can set GPU options in eager execution mode like so:

```py
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.333
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)

# model code as usual down here
```

I found this example in a GitHub fix for the RTX 2000 series [CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24496#issuecomment-464909727) GPU error.